# DynamoDB, Updating Multiple Nested Map Attribute

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I have a top level attribute and I want to simultaneously update multiple nested attributes. The params I am passing in are:

```
{
   "TableName":"LOCAL-Table",
   "Key":{
      "id":"1"
   },
   "UpdateExpression":"SET #param.#eb321fb16aab1745c55a8659be811f2d = :valeb321fb16aab1745c55a8659be811f2d , #param.#6e3c283fb60480af627ede2758e8e983 = :val6e3c283fb60480af627ede2758e8e983",
   "ExpressionAttributeValues":{
      ":valeb321fb16aab1745c55a8659be811f2d":{
         ...
      },
      ":val6e3c283fb60480af627ede2758e8e983":{
         ...
      }
   },
   "ExpressionAttributeNames":{
      "#eb321fb16aab1745c55a8659be811f2d":"eb321fb16aab1745c55a8659be811f2d",
      "#6e3c283fb60480af627ede2758e8e983":"6e3c283fb60480af627ede2758e8e983",
      "#param":"param"
   },
   "ReturnValues":"UPDATED_NEW"
}
```

It works when updating a single attribute, but when I put 2 in I get an error stating:

> The document path provided in the update expression is invalid for update

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this does work, the problem was related to poorly sequenced promises resulting in a race condition.